# Touchpad tap to click is not working

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I have added the following lines:

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

In both `.profile` and `.bashrc` files, but it didn't work.

It works whenever I execute the following command in terminal:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

But it only works for a few seconds, then I need to run it again, and sometimes this command doesn't work.

Mouse & Touchpadd settings seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I have added the following lines:

`synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
synclient TouchpadOff=0`
In both .bashrc file.

and use the `crontab -e` to create a cron job to execute the source command on the .bashrc

`* * * * * source ~/.bashrc`

Mouse & Touchpadd settings seems fine.